# What the meaning of "dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path" on OSX and how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, dyld

I had installed the Image::Magick Module (ImageMagick 7.0.9-25 OSX 10.14.6)

For installing I use this documentation:

https://imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

On running every Image::Magick script I got a OSX warning:

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/openexr/lib/libIlmImf-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libImath-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libHalf-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libIexMath-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libIex-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libIlmThread-2_4.24.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
```

What the meaning of the warning?

How can fix it?

Comment: I have a similar message in my logs on macos server... just installed imagick with extension via homebrew... image manipulation works via browser as far as I can tell...  something with file permissions maybe?